# passing connection string to DBcontext without using app.config

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, connection-string, dbcontext

i am new to using Code First approach. Please excuse me if i am missing something very basic.

I need to pass connection string to DBcontext but i can't that connection string to app.config since i am calling a nugget in the class itself which gives me the connection string.

```
Class A : Dbcontext , IA
{
    class A() : base () 
    {
        //call to nugget for giving a connection string
        var connString=nugget.connString();
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connString;
    }

}`
```

is this approch correct ? i cannot test this on my local system.
or should i pass the connString to base

class A() : base (connString)

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DbContext class has a constructor that you can pass your connection string while creating a new instance of it. The best approach here is to make a constructor for your Class A too and take your connection string arguments from outside, not inside your class. But if you're so sure about using having you connection string in your class, at least you should make it optional like this.

```
    public class MyDbContext : Dbcontext , IA
    {
        public static readonly _defaultConnString = nugget.connString();

        public class MyDbContext() : base(_defaultConnString) { }

        public class MyDbContext(string connString) : base(connString) { }
    }
```

Comment: This is throwing me an exception.
While resolving the unity for IA which is registered with A, exception is thrown saying "The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value."

Comment: @PRIYANARANG I'm not familiar with unity. but if this is some sort of dependency injection related issue, there must be a work around since it says "you must configure container" .. or you can just remove the second constructor with the string parameter and give it another try since you're probably using the first one.

Comment: The reason of exception must be multiple constructors i was using, by default, the call goes to constrictor with max number of parameters. As soon as i deleted the parameterized constructor , it is working fine